# an error: "the development server returned response error code: 500" is showing while running react native application

Tags: react-native

I'm running two terminals one is for the "npm start". and the other is for npx react-native run-android. I'm also using Windows 10 as an operating system. Any help is appreciated Thank you

Comment: are you using a device or a simulator?

Comment: im using a physical android device

Comment: is there any node_modules error? it said that there's an error with your react-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `react-native start`. Then try to use Android Studio for building. `react-native run-android` is not working for me but i am using this method.

Answer (score 0):

check if usb debugging is activated in the developer menu of your phone, then be sure that the phone is recognized using `adb devices` command, you should see a device listed with a number.

Comment: when i run 'adb devices' it shows that the physical android device is recognized. But it happened exactly when I installed the npm package of the navigation drawer >(npm i react-navigation-drawer). First, a warning was showing said: "Cannot connect to the Metro server". and when I restart the application (npm start & npx react-native run-android) separately, the error 500 showed up then

Comment: what version of react-navigation you have?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory

Comment: I think you should uninstall `react-navigation-drawer` and start a clean install following the docs of `react-navigation` : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: that was the same documentation i was using for my drawer navigator. or you mean it has installed wrongly? i'd be grateful if you suggest me another one doing no errors

Comment: You need to install the main module react-navigation then install the drawer module